# Explanation of replace method in Java

Tags: java

I often use the method `replace(CharSequence,CharSequence)` in Java, but today I encountered something I don't really understand.

When I do :

```
"|||".replace("||","| |");
```

Why it results in : `| ||` and not `| | |`? Why the second `|` can't be include in two patterns?

To resolve my problem I have to write `"|||".replace("||","| |").replace("||","| |");` which looks a bit redundant.

Any one have an explanation to help me understand better the mechanism behind?

**EDIT**

So it has been said that it's the particular case specify in the javadoc, but it's wrong the example is the following :

```
 * The replacement proceeds from the beginning of the string to the end, for
 * example, replacing "aa" with "b" in the string "aaa" will result in
 * "ba" rather than "ab".
```

So it's different from my case because the result "ba" is not a match for "aa" anymore. Whereas in my case the result "| ||" still contains the pattern.

Comment: Note that that particular use-case is explicitly mentioned in the javadoc of that method

Comment: @Robin Don't see that I refer to this doc http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29 They shouldn't remove this example...

Comment: You should read the doc of the replace method with the CharSequence (the method you mention in your question). On JDK7 it still contains this example

Comment: @Robin Oops I've not paid enough attention....

Comment: @Robin I read the example again and I have definitively not the same case that the one in the Javadoc. The Javadoc example is about order ; the result don't contains the pattern anymore is their case.

Comment: I don't see any problem with that. They don't state that the returned string does not contain the pattern anymore. It just happens that your example recreates the pattern while the one from the JavaDoc does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things going on here that could cause the confusion.  First, `replace` will not process the same character twice, so the middle `|` can only apply to a single replace.  Second, replace does not process the replacement characters, so after the first replace you will have `| ||`, but the 2nd `|` is part of the first replacement.

So basically what you get is after one replace, you have the first `||` is replaced and the remainder is `|` which does not match so the replace is complete.

Comment: Thanks for all answers! I was not really sure that the second `|` can't be include in two patterns. The documentation gives the example but not the reason of this behaviour. Now  I know!

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities for why `replace()` might behave the way you expect it to:

1. It could consider overlapping matches (in your example: match characters 1 & 2, and then 2 & 3). It does not do that.
2. It could substitute recursively, meaning that stuff that got added/changed as a result of a substitution would be eligible for further matches. It does not do this either.

Answer (score 1):

The replace starts by looking at the charsequence to find in your original string and once found, it says, ok the match starts in `start` and ends in `end`, let's replace that part with the replacement and then keep on looking for the next match from the `end + 1` position

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer on the why, but it is a good thing that

```
"|||".replace("||","| |");
```

does not result in `"| | |"`. If that would be the result, it means the replacement is also performed on a part of the String where replacements already took place.
That would make it very easy to write an infinite loop, e.g. `"|".replace("|", "||" );` would result in `"||||||...."` until your String becomes so big you run out-of-memory

Comment: +1 That's make sense! Otherwise, they would have to perform a check of patterns, and throw an exception if the second contains the first one, in this case. I understand it better now thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is

```
"|||".replace("|","| ");
```

or

```
"|||".replace("|","| ").trim();
```

if you don't want the last space.

The why i let for you to self study. Tip: search for regular expression replacement.

Comment: I'm not looking for a solution but for an explanation. it's right the doc show this case but there is not really an explanation.